# How to show dependencies' data in a tooltip in highchart gantt?

Tags: highcharts

How can I show dependencies' data (like their title) in a tooltip after hovering on each bar in highchart Gantt? **and also,** in this case, I want to hide dependencies arrows and just show their titles in a tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve it by using the `tooltip.formatter` callback function.

Here is a guideline: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qcgmjuvo/

```
tooltip: {
    formatter(tooltip) {
        let output = tooltip.defaultFormatter.call(this, tooltip),
                customText = this.point.options.customTooltipText;

        if (customText) {
                output.push(`<br><span>${customText}</span>`);
        }

        return output
    }
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter